# React Native: Native Modules Props

Tags: objective-c, react-native

I'm trying to make a Native Module in React Native. How can I access the URL in the view?

```
const MyView = requireNativeComponent('RNTImageFilter');
<MyView 
                    uri={'test'}
                    style={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red', height: 200, width: 200}}
                    />
```

ObjC:

```
@interface RNTImageFilterManager : RCTViewManager
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *uri;
@end

@implementation RNTImageFilterManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(RNTImageFilter)


- (UIView *)view
{
    UIView *picker = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 260)];
    picker.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.uri);
    
    return picker;
}

RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(uri, NSString *);

@end
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
RCT_CUSTOM_VIEW_PROPERTY(uri, NSString, RNTImageFilterManager) {
    NSLog(@"%@", json);
}
```